# Better style for HTML 'definition list' <dl> elements

Tags: feature-request, markdown, design

Among [allowed HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) there are tags which together form 'definition list', namely `<dl>` (definition list), `<dt>` (definition term), and `<dd>` (definition description) elements.  They can be useful among others to create e.g. glossary of terms... well, they could if they have any sensible style associated with them.

I would really like to have better **CSS style** associated with 'definition list'.

The following source (which has empty line after first item, which sometimes is and sometimes isn't visible in source view below).

```
<dl>
<dt>description term</dt> <dd>description definition</dd>

<dt>lorem ipsum</dt>
<dd>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</dd>
</dl>
```

generates the following output (**Edit**: which is now usable after changes described in [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting), though it still lacks hanging indent for description body):

---

description term

description definition

lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

---

which has horrible style, and is unusable (IMHO) as it is now.

In the case it got corrected the output looks like the following:

---

description term
description definition
lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

---

BTW. I couldn't find how to do 'definition list' using Markdown formatting: is there any?

Comment: Oh the HTMLanity! It does look horrid though.

Comment: It doesn't look like Markdown syntax supports definition lists: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting)

Comment: @zcoop98 It is now better (I have edited my request), but still could be improved.

Answer (score 19):

In this case, it looks like Markdown lacks... **removes sunglasses** **definition**.

It should at least indent the definition descriptions to provide some visual cue that you're dealing with a list not ordinary.

```
definition term
  definition description 

definition term
  definition description
```

The above is really just this:

```
<pre>
<b>definition term</b>
  definition description 

<b>definition term</b>
  definition description 
</pre>
```

But really should have some kind of difference between the `DT` and the `DD` on the `DL`. Unless there are plans to just tweak the CSS and they just have it on the... DL.

Comment: Could you show the source of the above?

Comment: He's using `pre` tags around the whole thing for formatting, with `b` tags for emphasis on terms.

Comment: @Jakub: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/a72b0623-a0e4-4813-8b23-5de7b977494a/view-source

Comment: +1 for dramatic aestetics. Shouldn't `pre` encode `<b>`?

Comment: @smeagol `PRE` just keeps the linebreaks, spaces and tabs in place while formatting in a fixed-width font. Tags still work.

Comment: It looks like `<pre>` is only about **Markdown** markup and preserving whitespace.  It is not the same as `<pre>` in HTML.

Comment: @Jakub: Contrary to popular belief, `<pre>` in HTML is also only about preserving whitespace.

Comment: @random: YEEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!!!!  (Incredibly late, but you deserved it.)

Comment: I would really love to see this implemented. I don’t care if we have to use real (or semi-real) HTML instead of Markdown. It’s worth it.

Answer (score 3):

In all these years of writing blog posts by hand (including typing out all the HTML tags) I have never really understood the purpose of the `<dt>`, `<dd>`, and `<dl>` tags.

I guess I am an HTML neanderthal.

Comment: If you're taking the `KBD` from Meta, at least give us the `DL-DT-DL`

Comment: "Definition lists vary only slightly from other types of lists in that list items consist of two parts: a term and a description."  "definition lists can be used to tie together any items that have a direct relationship with each other (name/value sets)."  Wikipedia markup uses `; term : definition`

Comment: One (not necessarily correct or complete) way of thinking is that items in unordered lists use the same marker, in ordered lists use an automatically generated marker, and in definition lists use an explicitly specified marker.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I have always thought that `<dl>` should work as follows:

```
<dl>

<li>

<dt>pony</dt>

<dd>any of various breeds of small gentle horses usually less 
    than five feet high at the shoulder</dd>

</li>

...

</dl>
```

because an item in a glossary consists both of the term and its definition.

Comment: If that's the case, you're writing it semantically wrong. `LI` only appear inside `OL` and `UL`.

Comment: @random I believe you are missing my point. I know that `<LI>` currently cannot appear in `<DL>`. I am saying it should with `<DT>` and `<DD>` providing the constituent parts of the **item**.

Comment: Why?  <dt> delimits the term, and <dd> delimits the definition.  Why would you need an extra list tag?

Comment: ... and why would you want to change the HTML standards? This is about styling existing HTML element structures with CSS - NOT changing standards.

Comment: @awe Oh, I can count a ton of reasons why HTML standards should be changed. In fact, I might be under the mistaken impression that they have changed many times. The fact that both the term and its definition form a whole, i.e. neither stands on its own, and therefore they should be contained in an item is either self-evident or not. The fact that they are not, makes styling hard.

Comment: As of HTML 5.2 (2017), it does work almost like this. Use `<div>` where you've written `<li>`, though.