# Why don't definition lists work on SE?

Tags: support, markdown

From [Allowed HTML Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), I find SE supports `<dl><dd><dt>`, so I copied an example from W3schools:

```
<dl>
<dt>Coffee</dt>
<dd>Black hot drink</dd>
<dt>Milk</dt><dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

And it seems...normal.

> Coffee
>
> Black hot drink
>
> Milk
>
> White cold drink

What's going on?

Comment: Are the downvotes just from people who ignorantly figured this was a programming question?

Answer (score 5):

They "work" just fine: if you open up your browser's DOM inspector, you'll see the text marked up just as you wrote it.

But there's no *styling* for definition lists. So they look just like normal text.

See: [Better style for HTML 'definition list' <dl> elements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22972/better-style-for-html-definition-list-dl-elements)