# Why do I get "+3" reputations ?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I notice I got [+3  reputations today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/249173/ave-maleficum?tab=reputation) for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224758/why-dont-definition-lists-work-on-se), the system tells me I get "+5" and "-2" on this question, but clearly this question has no upvotes or down votes. So why do I get "+3' reputations?

PS:Please don't up vote or down vote [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224758/why-dont-definition-lists-work-on-se).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you got +3 with a score of 0, you got one upvote and one downvote. 5 - 2 == +3

Here's the vote counts (which you can see with [the right privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)):

[image: the question has an upvote and a downvote on it]

But you don't need privilege to find the upvotes and downvotes if you know the score and rep.  The relationship is represented as a two equations in two variables:

```
    upvotes -     downvotes = score
5 * upvotes - 2 * downvotes = rep
```

Which has this as a matrix representation:

```
| 1  -1 |    | upvotes   |     | score |
|       | *  |           |  =  |       |
| 5  -2 |    | downvotes |     |  rep  |
```

The matrix above is  [nonsingular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)  and thus the linear system admits exactly one solution for any given combination of `score` and `rep`.  Nonsingularity is shown by computing that the determinant, 1*(-2) - (-1)*5, is nonzero.

In R, one would solve it thusly:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,5,-1,-2), 2,2)  # The matrix above
A
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1   -1
## [2,]    5   -2

solve(A, c(0, 3))  # Represent 0 score, +3 rep
## [1] 1 1
```

One upvote and one downvote.

The same technique works for answers, as the following matrix is also nonsingular:

```
|  1  -1 |
| 10  -2 |
```

Again, the determinant, 1*(-2) - 10*(-1), is nonzero.  And applied to this answer at this time, we have 98 points due to votes, and a score of 9.  So we solve:

```
|  1  -1 |    | upvotes   |   |  9 |
|        | *  |           | = |    |
| 10  -2 |    | downvotes |   | 98 |
```

Again using R to solve the system, we get 10 upvotes and 1 downvote:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,10,-1,-2),2,2)
solve(A, c(9,98))
## [1] 10  1
```

Comment: The magic trick. I get it, aha, thank you.

Comment: WOW, *now* that's a great answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan for the useful image.

Comment: Yep, that question's `+1/-1`.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because, while it is interesting, it is not a meaningful contribution. I appreciate the time you took to write this answer, but there are already common duplicates out there.

Comment: @Emracool Duplicates of the solution (with code!) for finding the upvotes/downvotes of your questions, when you lack the reputation to see them?  Could be, but I've yet to see one.

Comment: Actually, [it works even if they're not relatively prime](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u-d%3D1%2C10u-2d%3D26). The key factor here is we have a system of two linear equations, which can only ever have one solution (two lines only intersect once).

Comment: (Also, you might think this fails when score = rep = 0; [it doesn't](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u-d%3D0%2C10u-2d%3D0).)

Comment: @michaelb958 Indeed, the numbers need not be relatively prime.  I'm not going to prove it, but that they are relatively prime is a sufficient but not necessary condition for the matrix in question to be nonsingular.  In particular, it works for answers too.

Comment: Nice edit, would upvote again if possible.